# freeze while turning monitor off with xrandr

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon, xrandr, freeze

Question: How to turn one monitor off without freezeing the other?

My specs are below. I have two monitors. I want to turn my left monitor off, but when i run:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --off
```

my left monitor goes dark (as it should) and everything on my right monitor freeze and i can't click anything (I can only CTRL+ALT+F2 and reboot). I can move the mouse cursor on second monitor, but it seems like cinnamon is completely frozen.

I also tried turning left monitor off using display window from cinnamon, but the initial result is the same (cinnamon frozen) and after 30s, when cinnamon tries to restore the settings, monitor flickers and nothing actually is restored.

It was working some time ago, not sure when it stopped (maybe after some Mint update).

Any idea how to solve it? Thank you in advance for any tips.

**System:**

`System:    Host: XXXXXXX Kernel: 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.7
           Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: Dell product: OptiPlex 7010 v: 01
           Mobo: Dell model: 0GY6Y8 v: A03 Bios: Dell v: A19 date: 08/18/2014
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@60.02hz, 1680x1050@59.95hz
           GLX Renderer: AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-112-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.4`

**Xrandr:**

`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2960 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.08    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    60.00
   720x400       70.08
DisplayPort-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1-1 connected primary 1680x1050+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.08    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    60.00
   720x400       70.08
  1280x1024 (0x47) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x48) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1152x864 (0x49) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x4a) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0x4b) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4c) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4d) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x4e) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x4f) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x400 (0x50) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz`